# Преобразование типов в языке C#

Tags: c#

Если у значении тип `int` то `Convert.ToInt16`.
А если у значении тип `float` как преобразовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Convert.ToInt16 преобразовывает к short, а не к int. Для int нужен метод Convert.ToInt32.
2. для float нужен метод Convert.ToSingle

Comment: можете дать ссылки отвечающие на вопросы как преоброзовать типы,какие методы где использовать

Comment: @Zhandos неужели вас забанили в гугле?

Comment: есть такая конструкция:                  pay.payment_sum*ac.[PremiaPercent]. У обоих тип float, использовал Convert.ToSingle ,но не выводить

Comment: @Zhandos, вы сейчас о чем вообще? Вы же сами говорите, что у обоих операндов тип float. Так зачем вам вообще Convert?

Comment: спасибо исправил